# What can I do about this gap when my window is open?

Tags: windows

What can I do about this air gap when my window is open? This is a very old apartment and the windows are garbage; probably over 100 years old since it's a renovated factory.

I want to get air circulating in my apartment but I also want to keep out any tiny flying invaders.

I am currently using packing tape to seal the gap but I have to remove it every time I want to close the window.

There is probably another gap at the top that I can't reach. These windows don't seal well at all and are even dry rotting in some places.

[image]

Comment: I see a window, but I don’t see a gap. Could you take a picture of the gap and the frame around it?

Comment: I think it's the gap between the mobile part and the screen.

Answer (score 0):

move the screen outdoors so that it fills the space between the fixed part of the window and the window frame.